# NetParameter problem with execute caffe.exe

Tags: c++, caffe

I have successfully built caffe.exe with cuda11.1 without cudnn.

But when I execute the caffe.exe. It come out with this type of error.

```
[libprotobuf ERROR D:\ThirdPartyLibrary\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\text_format.cc:296] Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter: 16:11: Message type "caffe.WindowDataParameter" has no field named "config".
```

[error cmd screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtCRU.png)

My environment:

---rtx3090

---cuda11.1

---visual studio 2015

---win10

I had built caffe with cuda10.2 and cudnn7 before.
And it work with RTX Titan.
Not sure if this is related to the version of cuda or not.

By the way, Can Caffe support the higher cuda version anymore??

Comment: That is a protobuf error -- you likely have a typo or error in a configuration file. Nothing to do with CUDA at all

Comment: Thanks for your replay!!
I had used the same prototxt. The only difference is the cuda version.

Comment: Clearly that isn't the only difference because you can [see for yourself here](https://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers/windowdata.html) that WindowDataParameter clearly has no config field. So whatever you were using for source code before and now are not the same. And to repeat, this has nothing to do with CUDA at all

Comment: Thanks a lot!! After I add the new parameter named "config" to the caffe.pb and it work.